# How to split a long Go template function across multiple lines?

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a very long `printf` call in a Go template. Example:

```
{{ printf "mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s?authSource=admin&replicaSet=%s&readPreference=nearest&w=majority" .Values.rocketchat.mongo.username .Values.rocketchat.mongo.password .Values.rocketchat.mongo.database .Values.mongodb-replicaset.replicaSetName | b64enc | quote }}
```

How can I split this across multiple lines (like below)?

```
{{ printf "mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s?authSource=admin&replicaSet=%s&readPreference=nearest&w=majority"
    .Values.rocketchat.mongo.username
    .Values.rocketchat.mongo.password
    .Values.rocketchat.mongo.database
    .Values.mongodb-replicaset.replicaSetName
    | b64enc | quote }}
```

Comment: The only way to do that would be to change your function to take a composite type (such as a `struct` or `map`), then build that composite type line-by-line.  But don't do that. Generally speaking, but doubly so in templates, if you feel your lines are too long, it means you need to refactor with a simplification.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This cannot be done.  From the [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template) documentation:

> Except for raw strings, **actions may not span newlines**, although comments can.

Answer (score 3):

For posterity, since Go 1.16 you can have template actions span more than one line; from the [release notes](https://go.dev/doc/go1.16#:%7E:text=Newlines%20characters%20are%20now%20allowed%20inside%20action%20delimiters%2C%20permitting%20actions%20to%20span%20multiple%20lines.):

> Newlines characters are now allowed inside action delimiters, permitting actions to span multiple lines.

([example](https://go.dev/play/p/3j2gGodA5w3) [implementation](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/254257))

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use string literals instead, see some examples here: https://golang.org/src/html/template/example_test.go